# Conflicting TCP Socket Listener and Multithreaded Socket Worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, sockets, tcp

I'm currently working with an application comprised of three parts which is supposed to work multithreaded but, for some reason, I'm not being able to make it work correctly whenever I use more than one thread.

I've been over my code numerous times and although I did identify and done some improvements I still can't find my error.

So I have a client application that is sort of a benchmark application to test the service performance, that defines the number of threads on which a particular operation will run (basically, how many TCP Clients to instantiate).

Here is the code for that client:

```
private void stressTestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    server = txtServer.Text;
    port = Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text);

    if (this.numberOfThreads.Value != 0 && this.executionTime.Value != 0)
    {
        newThreads = new Thread[(int)this.numberOfThreads.Value];

        this.threadTimer = new Stopwatch();
        this.threadTimer.Reset();

        //Clear stressResultsBox
        this.stressResultBox.Items.Clear();
        this.totalOp = 0;
        this.opFinishedCheck = 0;
        this.xmlTrimed = XElement.Parse(this.inputTextBox.Text).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.numberOfThreads.Value; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (i == 0) //run once
                    threadTimer.Start();
                //Create Threads
                newThreads[i] = new Thread(ThreadSlot);
                newThreads[i].Start(); //Start Thread
                if (this.threadTimer.Elapsed.Seconds >= this.executionTime.Value)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                stressResultBox.Items.Add(ex.Message);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Client thread slot creation
/// </summary>
public void ThreadSlot()
{
    // Set different data in each thread's data slot.
    Thread.SetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("Random"), randomGenerator.Next(1, 200));

    int index = 0;
    int threadProgress = 0;
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
    {
        index = this.stressResultBox.Items.Add("Sent request, waiting for response");
    }));

    //Run thread until timeout
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.threadTimer.Elapsed.Seconds < this.executionTime.Value)
            {
                string response = SendRequest(server, port, this.xmlTrimed);
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                {
                    this.stressResultBox.Items[index] = "Thread: " + (index + 1) + " Operations: " + (threadProgress + 1) + " Time: " + threadTimer.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString() + "s " + threadTimer.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString() + "ms";
                    threadProgress++;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            { this.stressResultBox.Items[index] = ex.Message; }));
            break;
        }
    }
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { this.totalOp += threadProgress; this.opFinishedCheck += 1; }));
    if (this.opFinishedCheck == ((int)this.numberOfThreads.Value - 1))
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
            this.threadTimer.Stop();
            this.stressResultBox.Items.Add("#Total Operations: " + this.totalOp);
        }));
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// SendRequest handler
/// </summary>
/// <param name="server">server IP to send the request</param>
/// <param name="port">server port to send the request</param>
/// <param name="data">request</param>
/// <returns>server answer</returns>
private static string SendRequest(string server, int port, string data)
{
    IPAddress ipAddress = null;
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);
    for (int i = 0; i < ipHostInfo.AddressList.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (ipHostInfo.AddressList[i].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (ipAddress == null)
        throw new Exception("No IPv4 address for server");

    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

    client.Connect(ipAddress, port); // Connect
    NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
    writer.AutoFlush = true;
    writer.WriteLine(data);
    string response = reader.ReadLine();

    //reader.Close();
    //client.GetStream().Close();
    client.Close();

    return response;
}
```

This client makes calls to a TCP server which has two classes: A listener and a Worker. The worker is responsible for performing the operations and call a WCF service. This listener keeps listening for connections from the client and instantiates a Worker on separate threads for each client instance.
While debugging everything seems to be running correctly with Thread and Client instantiation.

So here's my Listener:

```
internal class SocketListenerService
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int port = 50000;
            AsyncService service = new AsyncService(port);
            service.Run(); // very specific service
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
} // Program

public class AsyncService
{
    private IPAddress ipAddress;
    private int port;

    public AsyncService(int port)
    {
        // set up port and determine IP Address
        this.port = port;
        string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);

        this.ipAddress = IPAddress.Any; // allows requests to any of server's  addresses

        this.ipAddress = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < ipHostInfo.AddressList.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (ipHostInfo.AddressList[i].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                this.ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (this.ipAddress == null)
            throw new Exception("No IPv4 address for server");
    } // AsyncService ctor

    /// <summary>
    /// SocketListener run method
    /// Initializes a socketworker for every client connection
    /// </summary>
    public void Run()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(this.ipAddress, this.port);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Service is now running on " + this.ipAddress.ToString() + ":" + this.port);
        Console.WriteLine("Hit <enter> to stop service\n");

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                //Threaded...
                SocketWorker sw = new SocketWorker(tcpClient);
                Thread workerThread = new Thread(sw.Run);
                workerThread.Start();

                //Not threaded...
                //sw.Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    } // Start

    private void threadSlot(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        SocketWorker sw = new SocketWorker(tcpClient);
        //sw.Run();
    }
} // AsyncServer
```

Then, I have a class which I call the Worker. The Worker will be responsible for performing the actual work/operations intended.
And here's my Worker:

```
internal class SocketWorker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// SocketWorker run method
    /// Starts processing the client request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tcpClient">tcpclient connection</param>
    /// 
    private TcpClient tcpClient = null;
    private int instanceCounter = 0;

    public SocketWorker(TcpClient tcpCli)
    {
        tcpClient = tcpCli;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SocketWorker run method
    /// Starts processing the client request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tcpClient">tcpclient connection</param>
    public async void Run()
    {
        instanceCounter++;
        Console.WriteLine(instanceCounter.ToString());

        try
        {
            while (tcpClient.Connected)
            {
                NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(networkStream);

                string request = reader.ReadLine();
                if (request != null)
                {
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
                    writer.AutoFlush = true;
                    string response = await Execute(request, tcpClient);//Executes the request
                    //Console.WriteLine("Response: " + response);
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync(response);
                    //writer.Close();
                    //tcpClient.GetStream().Close();
                    //tcpClient.Close();
                }
                else
                    break; // client closed connection
            }
            tcpClient.GetStream().Close();
            tcpClient.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            if (tcpClient.Connected)
            {
                tcpClient.GetStream().Close();
                tcpClient.Close();
            }
        }
    } //Run

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes client request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">received client xml</param>
    /// <returns>xml response to be sent to the client</returns>
    private async Task<string> Execute(string xml, TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceReferenceIISSrv.serviceClient clientService = new ServiceReferenceIISSrv.serviceClient();
            //Call the search service
            Task<byte[]> searchResult = clientService.SearchAsync(strct);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            clientService.Close();
        }

        //Console.WriteLine(ll);
        //tcpClient.Close();
        return ll;
    } // Execute
}
```

Finally, my WCF service is hosted on IIS using net.TCP protocol for communications and defined with the following ServiceBehaviour:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

Since this is a lot of information, here's the simplified scenario:

ClientTool => TCP Sockets -> Listener = new Worker => net.TCP -> WCF

I know this is a lot of code and most of you aren't really going to read it (I know I probably wouldn't as well), but I decided to keep it all here because I don't see any errors when instantiating any of the classes neither when initializing the threads.

But what's happening is that I'm only being able to get replies to one of the threads even if they start at the same time. If, I'm running a benchmark on one instance of the client tool with just one thread and then I start a benchmark on another instance of the client tool (on another computer, for example) the first instance stops getting replies and the second one works perfectly.

So, can anyone see anything I'm doing wrong? Also, does mixing Tasks as Threads present any sort of concurrency problems in this scenario?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Interesting case but there's just to much code here to audit. Closing. Why don't you delete everything that's not needed to demonstrate the problem? That would be about 80% here. You can revert from source control later.

Comment: @usr Yes I know it's just too much code in here. The reason I decided to post it all was because I suspected that the problem could be related to some definition further back on the code. Meanwhile, I also found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864721/multi-threaded-tcpclient-send-timeout-after-long-open-connection) and I'm on my way to test it.